# Prove that there's an $a$ such that $(a^2 +1 / p) = -1$ (Legendre symbol)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let a prime $p$ such that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Prove that there's an $a$ such that $(a^2 +1 / p) = -1$ (Legendre symbol)

I already proved in previous section that for every $a$: $$p\nmid a^2+1\tag 1$$.

I was guided to assume by contradiction that for all $a$: $(a^2 +1 / p) = 1$, and then I need to conclude that for all $z\in\mathbb Z$: $x^2 \equiv z\pmod{p}$ which contradicts the fact that there are (If I'm not mistaken) only $\frac{p+1}{2}$ (including zero) quadratic residues modulo $p$.

Formulating the assumption:
$$\forall a\in\mathbb Z \exists x\in\mathbb Z \text { such that } x^2 \equiv a^2+1 \pmod{p}$$

Now, my guess is that I need to utilize $(1)$ somehow at this point of the proof.

Also, I have in my mind two possible leads:

1. Maybe it can be shown that $a\to a^2+1 \pmod{p}$ is a bijection so it covers all possibilities $\pmod {p}$ (i.e. $0,\ldots, p-1$)
2. Some more ambitious lead is to look at:

$$1\pmod{p} \equiv x^{p-1}\equiv \left(x^2\right)^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv (a^2+1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \sum_{k=0}^{(p-1)/2} {{(p-1)/2}\choose{k}} a^{2k}$$

I'd be glad for guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: $a\to a^2+1$ is clearly not a bijection for $p>2$ ($f(-1)=f(1)$).

Comment: Okay, thanks for noting that.

Comment: An answer is contained [in this relatively recent thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2555453/11619). Lulu's (+1) argument also makes an appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $p>2$ (so there are non-squares $\pmod p$). Otherwise we make no assumption on $p \pmod 4$.

Consider the non-zero residues $\{1,2,3,\cdots, p-1\}$.  Let $r$ be the least of these which is not a square.  Then $r\neq 1$ and  $r-1$ is a square (clearly) and writing $r-1=a^2$ gives the example you need.  (This has nothing to do with the congruence of $p\pmod 4$).

Comment: What do you mean by "which is not a square"?

Comment: Some of those residues are squares and some are not.  Indeed, exactly $\frac {p-1}2$ of them are not.

Comment: Take, say, $p=13$ as an example.  The squares are $\{1,3,4,9,10,12\}$ Thus the non-squares are $\{2,5,6,7,8,11\}$.  Of these the least is $2$ and indeed $2=1^2+1$ is an example of what you are seeking.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it. Although, after understanding your approach I'm kinda confused about the tutor's guidance for this exercise (which is somewhat more complicated)

Comment: Well, I am certainly using the fact that non-squares exist $\pmod p$.  My argument fails for $p=2$ because all the non-zero residues are squares (there is only $\{1\}$). So I need $p>2$.  I don't see where $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ is meant to be used, mind you.

Comment: $p\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ was used to show that $p\nmid a^2 + 1$ (at previous section) and I guess it should be used in the tutor's approach.

Comment: lulu, first of all thanks for the suggested solution. Any chance you could explain how to use the tutor's guidance to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand what the guidance was.  My argument shows that either all the nonzero residues are squares or there exists a residue $a$ with the form you want.  So, to finish, you need to show that there are non-squares.  To me, that is obvious:  $(1)^2=(-1)^2$ so as soon as $p>2$ the squaring map is non-injective hence non-surjective.  But maybe your tutor had a separate argument for that which works in the special case $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.